# htaccess redirect using alphanumeric characters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, alphanumeric

I am having trouble redirecting from an old site containing links with alphanumeric characters.

Here is what I have:

```
Redirect 301 /itemlist.asp?depart=Entry+Doors&subcat=Wood+%26+Wrought+Iron&disnum=all /index.html
```

The `.htaccess` file does not recognize the old link as a url. I have searched all over but the answers are specific to the questions. It does not clearly help my situation. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Query string cannot be matched using `Redirect` directive. Use a `RewriteCond` in `mod_rewrite`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =depart=Entry+Doors&subcat=Wood+%26+Wrought+Iron&disnum=all
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What exactly did you try?